# .net asp .asax forbidden (Mono)

Tags: c#, asp.net, nginx, mono

I'm trying to run mono on fastcgi and nginx.

But everytime i want to access the page i'm getting the error

```
Application Exception
System.Web.HttpException
This type of page is not served.

Description: HTTP 403.The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden. The extension '.asax' may be incorrect. Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Details: Requested URL: /PathtoFile/Global.asax
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) <0x4042efa0 + 0x00127> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () <0x412e0000 + 0x044d2> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () <0x412d9c10 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0
```

On mono i'm getting

```
Duplicate name, SCRIPT_FILENAME, encountered. Overwriting existing value.
```

I'm running

```
Ubuntu 15.04
Mono 4
PHP 5
FastCGI
```